# How to get beacons UUID, when scanning for BLE

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using this library https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_reactive_ble for scanning the beacon. and for broadcasting a beacon I am using an android app called beacon simulator and it has got beacon UUID, majorID and minorID for each hosted beacon.

[image: d]

here the UUID is '0546b93b-f113-438d-8bab-b9e766dd'

but while scanning I am unable to look out for UUID instead I am getting this response in this structure.

```
DiscoveredDevice(id: 14:49:2F:BB:D5:97, name: , serviceData: {}, serviceUuids: [], manufacturerData: [76, 0, 2, 21, 5, 70, 185, 59, 241, 19, 67, 141, 139, 171, 185, 231, 102, 208, 17, 119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 191], rssi: -39)
```

Is there any way I can get the beacon's UUID in the format '0546b93b-f113-438d-8ba...'
Or any better way to uniquely identify a device? I know we can search for the device's Bluetooth address, but that just keeps on changing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.beaconzone.co.uk/blog/beacon-advertising-cheat-sheet/ has how to decode various beacon formats. The beacon you listed appears not to be an ibeacon as the manufacturer data for that would start `[76, 0, 2, ...`

Comment: @ukBaz so according to you we can convert this (manufacturerData) e.i. [76, 0, 2, 21, 5, 70, 185, 59, 241, 19, 67, 141, 139, 171, 185, 231, 102, 208, 17, 119, 0, 0, 0, 0, 191]  into UUID '0546b93b-f113-438d-8bab-b9e766dd' ?

Comment: Yes, `manufacturerData`  4 to 19 as hex is `0546b93bf113438d8babb9e766d01177` which should be the beacon UUID. From the start of the manufacturer data, `76, 0` is little endian so `0x004c` in the Assigned Numbers Document https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/ which is Apple Inc. `2` is how Apple identifies it as an ibeacon. 21 is the length in bytes that follow that are the beacon data. Next16 bytes are the UUID. Next 2 bytes are Major ID. Next 2 bytes are Minor ID. Final number is the transmit power of the beacon.